# Page redirect with variables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am simply trying, upon clicking a button, send the variable $task_id from my view to a specific function in my controller.  However, upon clicking the button, I get the error message:

```
The requested URL /ci/index.php was not found on this server.
```

I am not sure where the /ci/ is coming from?  In the browser address bar it has the correct url, but for some reason it's not working.  Is there a better way to send a variable to the controller from a view?

My Controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{

  public function index(){

    $data['task_id'] = 1;

    $this->load->view('instruction_view', $data);
  }

  public function practiceTask($task_id){
    //do some stuff
  }
}
```

My button handler in view:

```
$('#begin_practice').on('click', function(){
  window.location.href= "<?php echo base_url('practiceTask' + $task_id); ?>";
});
```

My base_url is set to:

```
'http://localhost:8888/main/'
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot controller name:

```
window.location.href= "<?php echo base_url('main/practicetask/' + $task_id); ?>";
```

Comment: It's usually something simple like that that I overlook!

Comment: It's always easy afterward. :) Thanks for check.